# Implementing a non-blocking receive in mpi4py python

Tags: python, mpi

I have n python processes running using mpi4py. They communicate one-to-one via channels. But I have to implement a non blocking receive. The actual task i want to perform is to check whether I have received any message in any of the incoming channels and if yes, then consume it. If no, then ignore it and continue the computation. Is there any way to implement this function.

Comment: I've not used `mpi4py`, but in `mpi`, you would (probably) be using an [`mpi_irecv`](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man3/MPI_Irecv.3.php)

Comment: Yup, you want MPI.Comm.Irecv to post the receives, and MPI.Request.Testany to see if any of the requests have completed.  Documentation [here](http://mpi4py.scipy.org/docs/apiref/index.html).